# I am getting minutesGap issue in ngx-timepicker after updated the cli

Tags: angular

I am getting minutesGap issue in ngx-timepicker after updated the cli

```
   core.js:5967 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'minutesGap' of undefined
        at TimepickerDirective.set (ngx-timepicker.directive.ts:94)
```

Comment: same problem, any fixes?

Comment: @JsYau the answer from Airrudi worked for me!

Answer (score 8):

Had the same problem, found my answer here: https://github.com/Agranom/ngx-material-timepicker/issues/358

In short, in your HTML file, move the [ngxTimepicker] to the beginning of your input tag. Like so:

```
<input [ngxTimepicker]="..." ........>
```